# Ubuntu 12.04 Slow Installs After SSD Upgrade

Tags: 12.04, ssd

OK.  So I just installed a new SSD into my laptop and put a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 onto the drive.  The OS install took about 45 minutes longer than it ever did with my HDD.  Whenever I go to update software and do the regular updates they take FOREVER.  Every update package seems to lag on "Unpacking Replacement".  I have already been through all of the threads and tried optimizing my drive for SSD to no avail.  The system itself is noticeably faster, it just slows way down when I begin updating or installing new software.  Any ideas?

Here is my system info:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
Samsung R540 Laptop
intel i3 Processor
8GB PC3-10600
Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz × 4 
60GB Corsair SSD Drive CSSD-V60GB2
```

Comment: Please name the hardware like SSD, motherboard, CPU...

Comment: I have added my system info

Comment: There seems to be a general issue with the stock firmware of that drive. That's all I could find until now: http://forum.corsair.com/forums/showthread.php?t=98194 http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233188 This does not look good, you'd better return the drive and get another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the drive itself or the firmware. Searching for the drive on the web brings up results with unhappy customers. The only advice I can give is to return the drive and look for a state of the art drive with good customer ratings. Intel is known as the leader when it comes to quality of SSDs and they don't seem to be extremely expensive anymore.

Comment: Well that explains why I got the drive for so cheap at Fry's. Lol.  Thank you though.  I am on my way back there now to return.

Comment: Just as I thought, too. :)